# while uploading a file into azure devops using Push API, The object '"' does not exist.' get displayed "typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to add a file into respos folder using below API's:

```
ado_req_headers_ATT = {'Content-Type':'application/octet-stream'}
Get_Branch_url = str(organization_url)+str('/_apis/git/repositories/')+str(ReposID)+str('/refs?filter=heads/&api-version=6.0')
print(Get_Branch_url)
Get_Branch_Details = requests.get(url=Get_Branch_url,headers=ado_req_headers_ATT,auth=('',ADO_AUTH_PAT))
#print(Get_Branch_Details.status_code)
print(Get_Branch_Details.text)
Get_Branch_Details=Get_Branch_Details.json()
for item in Get_Branch_Details["value"]:
    if item["name"] == **'refs/heads/XXX'**:
        old_object_ID = item["objectId"]
        old_object_name= item["name"]
print(old_object_name,":-",old_object_ID) **## Prints refs/heads/XXX : YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY**
```

The response for the above url includes:

```
    {
  "value": [
{...
  **"name": "refs/heads/XXX",
  "objectId": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY",**
  "creator": {
    "displayName": "AAAAAAAAAA",
    "url": "https://spsprodsin1.vssps.visualstudio.com/UUUUUU",
    "_links": {
      "avatar": {
        "href": "https://dev.azure.com/TTTTTT"
      }
    },
    "id": "MMMMMMMMM",
    "uniqueName": "PPPPPPPP",
```

And treating this Object ID: YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY as old ObjectID and trying to push a file into path: refs/heads/XXX using below API:

```
###### Push a File in  Ref_Devops-dev ###############################
ado_req_headers_ATT = {"Content-Type":"application/json-patch+json"}
push_file_url = str(organization_url)+str('/_apis/git/repositories/')+str(ReposID)+str('/pushes?api-version=6.0')
Body_data = {"refUpdates": [{"name": refs/heads/XXX,"oldObjectId":YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY}],"commits":[{"comment": "Added text file.","changes":[{"changeType": "add","item": {"path":"/test.txt"},"newContent": {"content": "# Tasks\n\n* Item 1\n* Item 2","contentType": "rawtext"}}]}]}
Body_data = json.dumps(Body_data)
print(Body_data)
Push_file= requests.post(url=push_file_url,headers=ado_req_headers_ATT,data=Body_data,auth=('',ADO_AUTH_PAT))
print(Push_file.json())
print(Push_file.status_code)
print(Push_file.text)
```

But the response were :

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF401035: The object 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY' does not exist.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server.GitObjectDoesNotExistException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server","typeKey":"GitObjectDoesNotExistException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

And sure missing a final step & basic as well. Any suggestions pls

Comment: Pls correct me, do any other api need to refer to get the object ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above error can be eliminated by referring the commit API instead of mentioned API & get the latest commit ID.